# Search for lines that do not have certain characters in a row

Tags: search

I have a news article which I need to edit up a bit. Basically, I need to search for all lines that do not contain characters t and h 2 or more times in a row and replace 4 letter words with character D in those lines. Have no idea where to start.
For example, I have this text

```
Animals are multicellular eukaryotic organisms which form a biological kingdom Animalia. 
Historically, Aristotle divided animals into those with blood and those without
```

And I want it to look like

```
Animals are multicellular eukaryotic organisms which D a biological kingdom Animalia.
Historically, Aristotle divided animals into those with blood and those without
```

Answer (score 1):

Not too hard, really, as such tasks can be translated into regexps in a very straightforward manner.

```
:v/tt\|hh/s/\<\a\{4}\>/D/g
```

`:v/.../` for all lines NOT matching a pattern

`tt\|hh` "tt" OR "hh"

`s/.../D/g` substitute ALL matches on a line with "D"

`\<...\>` "word" borders

`\a\{4}` exactly four Latin letters

> Have no idea where to start.

Read about regexps. In Vim's embedded help these are `:h usr_27.txt` and `:h pattern.txt`.